# How are nematic phases modelled?

Tags: spectroscopy, superconductivity

Nematic phases in superconducting materials are studied in both angular-resolved photoelectron spectroscopy (ARPES) and second harmonic generation (SHG) experiments. What techniques, if any, are used to model these phases?

Comment: Any luck with figuring this out?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.